# how to eliminate use of goto in switch case

Tags: c++

Basically I want to accept a particular character from a user and then using a switch case it passes the string related with that character case to another function .for eg.

```
case i:strcpy(str,"ice-cream");
    other_function(str);
    break;
```

If any default character got printed by the user then it should print default statement and again take character from user and check its case. I did this with `goto`, but is there any other option available to avoid or replace `goto` in this code.

```
p:  
    {
        cout<<"Choose account type:-\n"<<"Enter\ns :-saving\nc :-current\nf :-fixed\nr :-recurring"<<endl;
        char c;
        cin>>c;
        switch(c)
        {
            char t[20];
        case 's':
             strcpy(t,"saving");
             a[i].setype(t);
             break;
        case 'c':
             strcpy(t,"current");
             a[i].setype(t);
             break;
         case 'f':
             strcpy(t,"fixed");
             a[i].setype(t);
             break;
         case 'r':
             strcpy(t,"reccurring");
             a[i].setype(t);
             break;
         default:
             cout<<"Enter valid account type"<<endl;
             goto p;
         }
     }
```

Comment: `while(c != 'c' && c != 's' && c != 'f' && c != 'r')` ?

Comment: Search about loops in c++

Comment: Off-topic, but I'm curious. How did you come to use `goto`? You seem to be still learning C++, so how come `goto` came up before a loop or function?

Comment: for(;;) { switch(v) case a: ... break; ... case 'z': ... break; default: ...; `continue`;} `break`; }

Comment: @VictorGubin: That's pretty unreadable. moving the loop body to a method keeps it nice and readable.

Comment: Sure. As well as this switch generally is wrong design (or "code with the smell"), and should be replaced with some `std::unordered_map<char, std::string>` or something.

Comment: @VictorGubin -- for 4 simple alternatives like this I would **never** use `std::unordered_map`. There's too much memory overhead and code overhead.

Answer (score 9):

The whole `switch` should be hived off into a function, and its return value used to determine what happens to the loop next.

```
while (true) {
    std::cout << "Choose account type:\n" << std::flush;
    char c;

    if (cin >> c)
    {
       const bool result = HandleUserInput(a[i], c);
       if (result)
          break;
       else
          std::cout << "Enter valid account type\n";
    }
    else
    {
       // Input error - you'll want to do something about that
    }
}
```

And:

```
// Given a character representing an account type, sets
// the type of 'account' as appropriate. Returns false
// on failure.
bool HandleUserInput(Account& account, const char c)
{
    switch (c)
    {
        case 's':
           a[i].setype("saving");
           return true;

        case 'c':
           a[i].setype("current");
           return true;

        case 'f':
           a[i].setype("fixed");
           return true;

        case 'r':
           a[i].setype("recurring");
           return true;

        default:
           return false;
    }
}
```

*(Notice how I got rid of the `strcpy`, which doesn't appear to be necessary? Depends what `setype` [which is misspelled] does I suppose. Also, for a bonus point, consider using a map instead of the switch, if you don't care about a bit of a performance hit.)*

Bathsheba's suggestion is a valid alternative, though I suggest that a `return` will look much clearer inside a `switch` than will a `continue`, since the latter has meaning within other kinds of control flow statements, whereas the former never does.

Also note that, if you decide *not* to use a function for some good reason, there's actually nothing particularly wrong with your `goto`, and don't let the cargo cultists tell you otherwise!

Comment: This is an extremely sensible choice. Have an upvote.

Answer (score 7):

Yes there is. Since `continue` doesn't have a direct meaning in a `switch` block (cf. `break`), the presence of the former will apply to an appropriate outer loop control structure.

So something on the lines of

```
do {
    // your code here, starting with "Choose account type".

    ...

    default:
        std::cout << "Enter valid account type" << std::endl;
        continue; // back to the start of the do loop
    } // close the switch
    break; // fall out of the loop
} while (true);
```

will do it, and is fairly idiomatic C++.

Comment: Not idiomatic in my opinion (it's literally the first time in 10 years I see such code), but it is interesting!

Comment: It can be a bit confusing, but I've certainly seen it (and, indeed, written it) within just the last few years at least.

Comment: I'd probably use `goto`s to break out of the loop from the non-`default` cases and then let the `default` case loop around "naturally" (though I know the OP would prefer to avoid `goto`), but I have to admit that this is pretty clever and is also very tempting.

Answer (score 3):

Use a boolean flag:

```
bool isInputSuccessful = false;
while (!isInputSuccessful)
{
    cout<<"Choose account type:-\n";
    char c;
    cin>>c;
    isInputSuccessful = true;
    switch(c)
    {
        char t[20];
        case 's':strcpy(t,"saving");
                 a[i].setype(t);
                 break;
        case 'c':strcpy(t,"current");
                 a[i].setype(t);
                 break;
        case 'f':strcpy(t,"fixed");
                 a[i].setype(t);
                 break;
        case 'r':strcpy(t,"reccurring");
                 a[i].setype(t);
                 break;
        default:cout<<"Enter valid account type"<<endl;
                 isInputSuccessful = false;
    }
}
```

Before inputting from the user, this code sets the success flag to `true`, and if unsuccessful, returns it to `false`.

Alternatively, it could just set it to `true` in each successful case.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest dividing your code into a few functions. That will make it is easier to understand what each function is doing and how it is doing.

```
bool isValidAccountType(char c)
{
   return ( c == 's' || c == 'c' || c == 'f' || c == 'r');
}

char getAccountType()
{
   char c;
   cout<<"Choose account type:-\n"<<"Enter\ns :-saving\nc :-current\nf :-fixed\nr :-recurring"<<endl;
   while ( cin >> c )
   {
      if ( isValidAccountType(c) )
      {
         return c;
      }
      cout<<"Enter valid account type"<<endl;
   }

   // Wasn't able to get input.
   // Exit out of the program.
   exit(0);
}

void processAccount(char c)
{
   char t[20];
   switch(c)
   {
      case 's':strcpy(t,"saving");
               a[i].setype(t);
               break;
      case 'c':strcpy(t,"current");
               a[i].setype(t);
               break;
      case 'f':strcpy(t,"fixed");
               a[i].setype(t);
               break;
      case 'r':strcpy(t,"reccurring");
               a[i].setype(t);
               break;
      default:cout<<"Invalid account type"<<endl;
              return;
   }

   // Rest of the function.
}
```

Use the following in `main`.

```
char c = getAccountType();
processAccount(c);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you put this code into a function, you can use a `return` statement to exit the loop:

```
const char* enter() {
    for (;;) {
        std::cout << "Choose account type: ";
        char ch;
        std::cin >> ch;
        switch(ch) {
            case 's': return "saving";
            case 'c': return "current";
            case 'f': return "fixed";
            case 'r': return "recurring";
        }
        std::cout << "Invalid input.\n";
    }
}
```

Now you can call this function and use its result:

```
char t[20];
strcpy(t, enter());
a[i].set_type(t);
```

Answer (score -1):

While all the other examples are very interesting, I usually stay away from `true` in the loop condition wherever it is possible.

In this case it would be correct to move the handling of the cases into a function by itself and use the returning result of the function to continue the actions.

First declare some predefined return results.

```
enum class Action_Result
{
    Ok,
    Error,
    Invalid_account,
    Quit
    /*...*/
};
```

Next make the function return the predefined results. (Notice that instead of `break` in the `case`, `return` is used to break out the function and also return the action result.

```
Action_Result handle_account_type(char c /*...*/)
{
    switch (c)
    {
        char t[20];
        case 's':
            strcpy(t, "saving");
            a[i].setype(t);
            return Action_Result::Ok;
        case 'c':
            strcpy(t, "current");
            a[i].setype(t);
            return Action_Result::Ok;
        case 'f':
            strcpy(t, "fixed");
            a[i].setype(t);
            return Action_Result::Ok;
        case 'r':
            strcpy(t, "reccurring");
            a[i].setype(t);
            return Action_Result::Ok;
        default:
            return Action_Result::Invalid_account;
    }
}
```

Then in the main loop we can make a decision based on the result of the handling function. Notice how the loop condition is now easy to understand, why the loop will continue to execute, and when it will stop looping. Also all the input and output is in the main function, separate from the actions (adhering better to the Single Responsibility Principle) .

```
int main()
{
    Action_Result account_handled_result = Action_Result::Error;

    do
    {
        cout << "Choose account type:-\n"
             << "Enter\ns :-saving\nc :-current\nf :-fixed\nr :-recurring"
             << endl;
        char c;

        if (cin >> c)
        {
            if (c == 'q')
                account_handled_result = Action_Result::Quit;
            else
                account_handled_result = handle_account_type(c);
        }
        else
        {
            account_handled_result = Action_Result::Error;
        }

        if (account_handled_result == Action_Result::Invalid_account)
             cout << "Enter valid account type" << endl;

    } while (account_handled_result != Action_Result::Quit);
}
```